# Customize cors-anywhere

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, cors, cors-anywhere

I have deployed (hosted) [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/) in Heroku, but i don't know how to customize it.
For example, I want to add a site link in whitelist.
I get data from this link: http://fmon.asti.dost.gov.ph/dataloc.php?param=rv&dfrm=null&dto=null&numloc=1&data24=1&locs[]=711

How will I do it? I have tried touching the server.js file:

```
// Listen on a specific host via the HOST environment variable
var host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
// Listen on a specific port via the PORT environment variable
//var port = process.env.PORT || 443;
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Grab the blacklist from the command-line so that we can update the blacklist without deploying
// again. CORS Anywhere is open by design, and this blacklist is not used, except for countering
// immediate abuse (e.g. denial of service). If you want to block all origins except for some,
// use originWhitelist instead.
var originBlacklist = parseEnvList(process.env.CORSANYWHERE_BLACKLIST);
//var originWhitelist = ['http://fmon.asti.dost.gov.ph/dataloc.php','https://fmon.asti.dost.gov.ph/dataloc.php','http://fmon.asti.dost.gov.ph','https://fmon.asti.dost.gov.ph'];
var originWhitelist = parseEnvList(process.env.CORSANYWHERE_WHITELIST);
function parseEnvList(env) {
  if (!env) {
    return [];
  }
  return env.split(',');
}

// Set up rate-limiting to avoid abuse of the public CORS Anywhere server.
var checkRateLimit = require('./lib/rate-limit')(process.env.CORSANYWHERE_RATELIMIT);

var cors_proxy = require('./lib/cors-anywhere');
cors_proxy.createServer({
  originBlacklist: originBlacklist,
  originWhitelist: originWhitelist,
  requireHeader: ['origin', 'x-requested-with'],
  checkRateLimit: checkRateLimit,
  removeHeaders: [
    'cookie',
    'cookie2',
    // Strip Heroku-specific headers
    'x-heroku-queue-wait-time',
    'x-heroku-queue-depth',
    'x-heroku-dynos-in-use',
    'x-request-start',
  ],
  redirectSameOrigin: true,
  httpProxyOptions: {
    // Do not add X-Forwarded-For, etc. headers, because Heroku already adds it.
    xfwd: false,
  },
}).listen(port, host, function() {
  console.log('Running CORS Anywhere on ' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

but when I access the data and look at the console log, it returns a 403 error which is forbidden.

Comment: 403 may not be due to cors issue. For cors issue in most of the case you may see this 
**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'yourUrl' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400**

Comment: But when I return the settings to default, it works fine. I just want to add a specific site in the `originWhitelist` option to avoid other using my self-hosted cors-anywhere

Comment: @MattMateo Check my answer if that makes sense. Leme know

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE: When you say self hosted CORS it will only work for your site to
>   proxy. CORS setting on your server is for you not for the list of
>   sites you mentioned. They will be having their own CORS filters setup.

403 actually refers to the forbidden resource rather than a CORS Issue. Cors issue will look something like as follows:-

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'yourUrl' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400**

For cors-anywhere the whitelisting code is pretty simple as mentioned below:-

```
// Listen on a specific host via the HOST environment variable
var host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
// Listen on a specific port via the PORT environment variable
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var cors_proxy = require('cors-anywhere');
cors_proxy.createServer({
    originWhitelist: ['http://fmon.asti.dost.gov.ph'], // Allow all origins
    requireHeader: ['origin', 'x-requested-with'],
    removeHeaders: ['cookie', 'cookie2']
}).listen(port, host, function() {
    console.log('Running CORS Anywhere on ' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

This should Ideally work for you with your application calling this somewhere.

---

> If you are getting 403 while accessing this URL from your application
>   then be sure the URL you mentioned is protected and you must get
>   proper authentication done before requesting it.

---

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, will the whitelist still work when I use this link `http://fmon.asti.dost.gov.ph/dataloc.php` instead of the link with specific value `http://fmon.asti.dost.gov.ph/dataloc.php?param=rv&dfrm=null&dto=null&numloc=1&data24=1&locs[]=711`?

Comment: @MattMateo you are whitelisting a domain name not the parameters associated. Its only the domain name. so use `http://fmon.asti.dost.gov.ph` . This should work for you. I have updated my answer as well. Just use the DOMAIN NAME

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, I have tried it but returns `XML Parsing Error: syntax error`.

Comment: and when i follow the link : `Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with`..I don't understand, it was on the requireHeader

Comment: refer to this, may be this will clarify your doubts https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/39 & https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/7

Comment: @MattMateo So from my understanding your front end requests must have these headers else it wont go through. Just go through the above two URLS. Hope this helps

Comment: @MattMateo Does this work? If it was helpful give a thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

I spent 3 days looking for the cause, got a 403 error for some sites and realized that the problem may be that they can not accept requests from "origin" different from theirs.
I just tried removing those headers on the proxy server and everything worked!

```
removeHeaders: ['origin', 'referer']
```